# What is development and deployment mode in Xcode active configuration?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

What is development and deployment mode in Xcode active configuration and what is difference between development and deployment mode? are they same as debug and release mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In earlier versions of Xcode, Apple used "Development" and "Deployment" (and also "Default") as the names for the build configurations. Later on, they switched to "Debug" and "Release", which is a bit easier to distinguish between.

"Development" would correspond to "Debug", and "Deployment" would correspond to "Release".